# CSS fluid image background not working in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fluid-images

I am trying to implement fluid image background for one of my webpage. It works perfectly in Chrome but I can't get it to work in Firefox. I have png images of two squares which will resize proportionally when browser window is resized.

**Here's the html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Test Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent_div">
    <div id="bluesquare_div"></div>
    <div id="yellowsquare_div"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here's the CSS:**

```
body{
    background: #444444;
}

#parent_div{
    display: flex;
}

#bluesquare_div{
    width: 50%;
    background: url("bluesquare.png");
    height: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}


#yellowsquare_div{
    width: 50%;
    background: url("yellowsquare.png");
    height: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The problem is I don't see any output in Firefox. If I don't use `display:flex` then I can see the two squares in Firefox, but my webpage requires the use of flexbox, so I can't drop it.

Anyone has any idea why its not working in Firefox ?

**Here's the screenshot for Chrome version: 55.0.2883.87 m**

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

**And here's the screenshot for Firefox version: 50.1.0**

[image: FireFox Screenshot]

Comment: on digging more, just came across this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502702/flex-elements-ignore-percent-padding-in-firefox

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the `padding-top: 50%` given for the flex-items!

`Margin`s / `padding`s are normally resolved against the `width` of the containing block instead of its `height`. But in the case of `flexbox` there is some confusion among the User Agents (browsers) - I guess:

1. *Chrome* resolves based on the `width` of flex-items
2. *Firefox* resolves based on the `height` of flex-items

See the warning in [CSS Flexbox Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins):

> Authors should avoid using percentages in paddings or margins on flex
>   items entirely, as they will get different behavior in different
>   browsers.

Ideally you'll need to think of another way - maybe as a fix you can you *viewport* units for `padding` instead of percentages and you don't need `height: 0` - see demo below:

```css
body {
  background: #444444;
}
#parent_div {
  display: flex;
}
#bluesquare_div {
  width: 50%;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 50vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#yellowsquare_div {
  width: 50%;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 50vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="bluesquare_div"></div>
  <div id="yellowsquare_div"></div>
</div>
```